# How to retrieve data from two tables related using a third table, SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables(simplified)

```
movie(id int primary key identity, title varchar(20) not null)
genre(id int primary key identity, type varchar(10) not null)

movie_genre(movie_id int references movie(id), 
            genre_id int references genre(id), 
            primary key(movie_id, genre_id))
```

Data in movie

```
id          title
---------------------------
1     |     Inception
2     |     The Dark Knight
```

Data in genre

```
id          type 
---------------------
1     |     action 
2     |     adventure 
3     |     thriller
```

Data in movie_genre

```
movie_id          genre_id 
----------------------------
1               |     1 
1               |     2 
2               |     1 
2               |     3
```

I want to display movie name with its genre types displayed in one column. So, the output would be

```
title              |     genres 
-----------------------------------------
Inception          |     action adventure 
The Dark Knight    |     action thriller
```

I tried to do it in this way

```
select 
    movie.title, genre.type 
from 
    movie, genre 
where 
    movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id 
    and genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id;
```

but it says :

> The multi-part identifier "movie_genre.movie_id" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "movie_genre.genre_id" could not be bound.

I am very new to SQL, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit :**
Using

```
SELECT G.[Type] ,M.[Title]
FROM movie_genre MG  
LEFT JOIN genre G ON MG.genre_id = G.ID
LEFT JOIN movie M ON MG.Movie_ID = M.ID
```

**OR**

```
select movie.title, genre.type 
from movie, genre, movie_genre
where
movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id 
and genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id;
```

The output is now,

```
    title              |     genres 
-----------------------------------------
Inception          |     action
Inception          |     adventure 
The Dark Knight    |     action
The Dark Knight    |     thriller
```

How could I display genres in one row?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I have yet to learn what is inner join, outer join, left join etc. So, I am not using them for simplicity. thanks anyways.

Comment: Learn them - right now. Stop using stuff that's been deprecated for over 20 years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT G.[Type] 
       ,M.[Title]
FROM movie_genre MG  
LEFT JOIN genre G ON MG.genre_id = G.ID
LEFT JOIN movie M ON MG.Movie_ID = M.ID
```

### To get a list

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.[Title]
      ,STUFF((
           SELECT ' ' + G.[Type] 
           FROM genre G INNER JOIN movie_genre MG
           ON  MG.genre_id = G.ID
           WHERE MG.Movie_id = Mov.Movie_id
           FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1, '') Genre
FROM movie_genre Mov  
INNER JOIN movie M ON Mov.Movie_ID = M.ID
```

### OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT M.[Title]
      ,STUFF(List,1,1, '') Genre
FROM @movie_genre Mov  
INNER JOIN @movie M 
ON Mov.Movie_ID = M.ID
             CROSS APPLY 
                       (
                       SELECT ' ' + G.[Type] 
                       FROM @genre G INNER JOIN @movie_genre MG
                       ON  MG.genre_id = G.ID
                       WHERE MG.Movie_id = Mov.Movie_id
                       FOR XML PATH('')
                       )Gen(List)
```

### [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/38208)

Answer (score -2):

I believe you will need to add the 'movie_genre' to FROM, e.g:

```
SELECT movie.title, genre.type FROM (movie, genre, movie_genre) WHERE ....
```

Comment: It's not valid SQL syntax.